# How to convert longitude/latitude (WGS-84) to X / Y coordinates (Pixmap)

Tags: geometry, coordinates, converters, geospatial

I've got a big number of nodes (lon,lat) in WGS-84 and I need to draw them on a Pixmap, so I have read a lot of Q&A here, but haven't found the algorithm how to convert lon/lat from WGS-84 to a x/y coordinates. By the way, I need to draw a simple scheme of map. Any ideas?

Comment: Is this another qt question?  It's unclear.

Comment: @John, no I'm really stuck with this. I don't understand how I should convert wgs-84 to x/y so there are main problem, because if I don;t know the right coordinates I can't draw them, so why I asked this question

Comment: I asked because I don't know what a `Pixmap` is.  But I can answer if you're stuck on getting it to a generic XY system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To go from WGS-84 latitude and longitude to an two-dimensional map, you first need to consider what kind of projection you have.  This is because one minute of arc, for example, could mean different distance changes over a particular projection.  You're mapping an ellipsoid to a plane, so you're going to get some distortion somewhere.

But for a simple case, let's say that your area is small enough, and close enough to the equator, that the change in angle (latitude or longitude) corresponds to a *constant* change in distance on the map (Y or X).

So, if you have a 600*600 image of a particular area, and it corresponds to a 10-minute by 10-minute area of the earth that has an upper-left corner at 30 degrees north, 40 degrees west.

To locate the pixel where 29 degrees, 55 minutes north, 39 degrees, 57 minutes west, we use a proportion for both latitude and longitude:

```
5' / 10' = Y / 600 pixels --->   Y = 300 (from the top edge)
3' / 10' = X / 600 pixels --->   X = 180 (from the left edge)
```

Hope that helps.